How to set XZ_DEFAULTS for right-click menu in Ubuntu 24.04
I've put XZ_DEFAULTS="-C sha256 -T 0 -1 " into /etc/environment. This works for compressing .xz files in bash shell, but doesn't work if the .xz file is generated by right-click menu
E.g. In shell,
touch a && tar -caf a.tar.xz a && xz -l a.tar.xz
Strms  Blocks   Compressed Uncompressed  Ratio  Check   Filename
1       1        200 B     10.0 KiB  0.020  SHA-256 a.tar.xz

But if you ompress any file as a .tar.xz by right-click menu, then check it with xz -l command:
xz -l created_by_right_click_menu.tar.xz 
Strms  Blocks   Compressed Uncompressed  Ratio  Check   Filename
1       1        172 B      1,536 B  0.112  CRC64   created_by_right_click_menu.tar.xz

See, the check method is CRC64 but SHA-256 as expected.
So, where can I set XZ_DEFAULTS for right-click menu?
Is it located in /usr/share/applications/? But I cannot determine which one I shoult edit.
Thanks!

I think the default Ubuntu Files application (nautilus) now handles compression/archiving internally rather than invoking external utilities like xz, doesn't it?

@steeldriver, Thanks for your tips! It's nautilus, and nautilus call gnome-autoar. I've fired an issue to gnome-autoar https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-autoar/-/issues/50
